# Lubuntu - pcmanfm does not fully update on first boot

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

An old 32 bit AMD Sempron 3400+ is running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.  It's used as a disaster backup so it's stuffed full of old hard drives. The problem arises on first boot when all the drives are not displayed in the left panel of `pcmanfm`. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Rebooting shows all the drive icons, connected network shares, etc:
[image]

Rebooting is an adequate workaround for what I use this system for, but as an Ubuntu learner, I'm curious to know what is going on, and how to diagnose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a superior workaround, at least: restart `pcmanfm` by opening a terminal and issuing the following commands:

```
killall pcmanfm
pcmanfm
```